# How to optimize Performance Remote Desktop C#

Tags: c#, windows, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm building a **C#** program like Windows Remote Desktop Connection.

I use Microsft RDP Client Control - version 8 to do that

There are some features I don't know how to do.

- Disable (Enable) Desktop Backround
- Font Smoothing
- Visual style

I've found most of features at **AdvancedSettings** -> **AdvancedSettings8**. But I can't find these features there.

Can anybody help me?